# Docker fails to start in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, docker

Docker is failing to start on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, `journalctl -xe`:

```
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36.651922900+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=30689
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" module=containerd revision=773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88 version=v1.0.3
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.content.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.snaps
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.differ.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.gc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." module=containerd type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd-debug.sock" module="containerd/debug"
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg=serving... address="/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock" module="containerd/grpc"
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36+01:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.007536s" module=containerd
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC kernel: device-mapper: table: 253:0: thin-pool: unknown target type
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC kernel: device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: time="2018-06-09T12:36:36.824772814+01:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver devicemapper failed: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool)
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC dockerd[30680]: Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devicemapper: Error running deviceCreate (CreatePool) dm_task_run failed
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 09 12:36:36 James-DevPC systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Tried literally everything and pulling my hair out now, any ideas?

Comment: What version of docker? The 18.06 docker has not been released still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to install docker-ce in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS following steps from [this tutorial](https://crunchytechbytz.wordpress.com/2018/06/25/how-to-install-docker-in-ubuntu-18-04/) -

Essentially you will run following commands -

1. install the dependencies  first -

   ```
   $ sudo apt install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
   ```
2. add the GPG key for the official Docker repository to the system:

   ```
   $ curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Add the Docker repository in sources.list.d to APT sources using below command

   ```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable edge"
   ```
4. verify if you are able to install Docker from Docker repository

   ```
   $ apt-cache policy docker-ce
   ```
5. Finally,  install Docker CE package with below command –

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
   ```

Voila, you have installed Docker-CE. you can verify installation by checking the version of  docker-ce installed

```
$ docker --version
```